# The example of convex program for KKT

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Is the example of convex programming problem (convex program) for which $\exists \lambda = (\lambda_0, ... ,\lambda_m)$ s.t. Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions are met but $\dot{x}$ isn't minimum?

X - linear space. $f_i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$ - convex functions, $i \in \{0,m\}$

Convex programming problem: 
$$ \cases{f_0(x) \rightarrow \inf \\
f_i(x)\leq 0, i \in \{1,m\}}$$

For $\lambda = (\lambda_0, ... ,\lambda_m)$ let $L(x, \lambda) = \sum f_i(x)\lambda_i$

$\dot{x}  - \text{solution}$

Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions:

1. $ \displaystyle\min_{x \in X} L(x, \lambda) = L(\dot{x}, \lambda)$
2. $ \lambda_i \geq 0, \quad i \in \{0,m\}$
3. $ \lambda_i f_i(\dot{x}) = 0, \quad i \in \{1,m\}$

Comment: This is a rather odd version of the KKT conditions.  Are you willing to assume differentiability of the $f_{i}$ functions?

Comment: Also you've left out the requirement that $f_{i}(\dot{x})\leq 0$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$.

Comment: @Brian Borchers functions can be differentiable but they must be convex.

Comment: @Brian Borchers if $\dot{x}$ is solution it must satisfy convex program's expressions. The requirement that $_(˙) ≤ 0 $ follows from this.

Comment: It's a standard theorem that if the $f_{i}$ are convex, $0$ is in the subgradient of $L(\dot{x} ,\lambda )$, $\lambda \geq 0$, $f_{i}(x) \leq 0$, and $\lambda_{i}f_{i}(x)=0$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$, then $\dot{x}$ is a minimum.

Comment: @Brian Borchers  Are you thinking that finding of the example is impossible?

Comment: Yes.  Unless there's some "trick" hidden in the odd wording of your question, the standard theorem eliminates any possibility of such an example.

Comment: @Brian Borchers in sufficient condition of minimum it is necessary that $\lambda_0 >0$. That is, the counterexample should be built with $\lambda_0=0$.

Comment: Normally, the KKT conditions are written with $\lambda_{0}$ scaled to 1.   You should probably clarify this in your statement of the question.